# Is there any way to make a span of text bulge in the middle using just transform?

Tags: css

A link to the fiddle is at the bottom.

Is there a way to bulge a text node by applying transform styles to it's parent container?

**HTML**

```
<span class='manual-labor-1'>e</span>
<span class='manual-labor-2'>s</span>
<span class='manual-labor-3'>c</span>
<span class='manual-labor-4'>h</span>
<span class='manual-labor-5'>e</span>
<span class='manual-labor-6'>w</span>

<br/><br/><br/>

<span class='just-css-3'>eschew</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.just-css-3 {
    /* ultimate troll wonders if there is a way to do create the same effect using just css3 (tansform?) */
}

    /* begin this is all garbage */
    color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    transform:rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-180deg); 
    -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(-180deg);
    /* end this is all garbage */
}

.manual-labor-1{ font-size:20px; }
.manual-labor-2{ font-size:50px; }
.manual-labor-3{ font-size:90px; }
.manual-labor-4{ font-size:90px; }
.manual-labor-5{ font-size:50px; }
.manual-labor-6{ font-size:20px; }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uyCZj/3/

Comment: after much searching of the interwebs, I think not.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not yet, it seems. Not until we get the ::nth-letter() pseudo-selector.

[A Call for ::nth-everything](http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/)
[CSS :nth-letter()](http://www.bram.us/2012/04/13/css-nth-letter/)

In the meantime, you can try using [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com), a jQuery plugin for typography.